# Azure FHIR server creating a patient

Tags: c#, fhir-server-for-azure

I'm trying to get this [Fit on FHIR project](https://github.com/microsoft/fit-on-fhir/tree/main) working, and I got stuck creating a new patient after the user confirmed access to GoogleFit data. This is the code for creating a new patient.

```cs
if (patient == null) {
  patient = await _resourceManagementService.EnsureResourceByIdentityAsync < Patient > (
    platformIdentifier,
    platformSystem,
    (p, id) => p.Identifier = new List < Identifier > {
      id
    });

  identifierToAdd = new Identifier(externalSystem, externalPatientId);
}
```

where `_resourceManagementService` is of type `Microsoft.Health.Extensions.Fhir.Service.ResourceManagementService`

The parameters passed to the function are:

`string platformIdentifier = 000000000000000000000` (Google Subject frow JWT)

`string platformSystem = https://accounts.google.com`

`EnsureResourceByIdentityAsync` method makes two requests:

1. HTTP GET - to check if a resource exists.
2. HTTP PUT - If a resource doesn't exist, it creates it

When the PUT request is executed, the FHIR returns this error: `BadRequest: Conditional operation on Patient was not attempted because search criteria was not selective enough`

What am I doing wrong?